# Access a page only if a user has admin role (React, Express, NodeJS, MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I want to allow to access a page, "Users" which show all the users registered on the website, only if the user is admin,

This is the component of the page :

```
<Route path="/users" exact component={Users} />
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work :

```
Router.js

<AdminRoute path="/users" exact component={Users} />



AdminRoute/index.js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import M from "materialize-css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function AdminRoute({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);

  async function loadUser() {
    try {
      const dataUser = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/users/my-account/${auth.user.id}`
      );
      setUser(dataUser.data);
      console.log("user ", user); <-- returns well an object with isAdmin = 
      true
      M.AutoInit();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
      loadUser();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        auth.isAuthenticated && user.isAdmin ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AdminRoute);
```

**The main issue is that if when an admin account, I get redirected because the user is still at false, so I need to find a way to render component only after loaduser funciton is done ?**

Comment: what you are getting in  auth.isAdmin  ?

Comment: I sense the problem is with the state, auth prop is not getting passed? or auth does not have the requried property isAdmin? could you provide code snippet for state?

Comment: @PrakashKarena I'm using an admin account right now, I see that isAdmin = true, but I get redirected or I was supposed to get to the page

Comment: are you getting your isAdmin?

Comment: @PrakashKarena i just edited the question, user.isAdmin= rue and isAuthenticated = true, but I still get redirected

Comment: @Danish i just edited the question, user.isAdmin= rue and isAuthenticated = true, but I still get redirected

Comment: Solved your problem or not

Comment: @Versifiction you need to wrap the component in order to wait for the loadUser to complete, or use history add it into destructing..

Answer (score 1):

Is this some kind of nested route? I'm sure you could set this up to work on your routing page, but I've always done the work in page itself using a truthy and statement.

```
{isAdmin && <div />}
```

Before you call the render() on your component, you could always ask `if (!isAdmin) props.history.push('/');`

import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

```
// This example has 3 pages: a public page, a protected
// page, and a login screen. In order to see the protected
// page, you must first login. Pretty standard stuff.
//
// First, visit the public page. Then, visit the protected
// page. You're not yet logged in, so you are redirected
// to the login page. After you login, you are redirected
// back to the protected page.
//
// Notice the URL change each time. If you click the back
// button at this point, would you expect to go back to the
// login page? No! You're already logged in. Try it out,
// and you'll see you go back to the page you visited
// just *before* logging in, the public page.

export default function AuthExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <AuthButton />

        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/public">Public Page</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/public">
            <PublicPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/protected">
            <ProtectedPage />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(cb, 100); // fake async
  },
  signout(cb) {
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};

function AuthButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  return fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
    <p>
      Welcome!{" "}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          fakeAuth.signout(() => history.push("/"));
        }}
      >
        Sign out
      </button>
    </p>
  ) : (
    <p>You are not logged in.</p>
  );
}

// A wrapper for <Route> that redirects to the login
// screen if you're not yet authenticated.
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

function PublicPage() {
  return <h3>Public</h3>;
}

function ProtectedPage() {
  return <h3>Protected</h3>;
}

function LoginPage() {
  let history = useHistory();
  let location = useLocation();

  let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  let login = () => {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(() => {
      history.replace(from);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You must log in to view the page at {from.pathname}</p>
      <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Click here for more info!](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Comment: it looks like my user hook is still at false, when the component renders, I need to find a way to return ONLY after my loadUser() is done

Comment: The example I've shown should cause the component to render after isAdmin is updated.

Comment: FYI, my above answer works if you move your logic to the page/container in question.

Comment: I can't use props.history.push because I destructured props in the function AdminRoute({...}), do you know how can I do a trick to use history ?

Comment: My solution is to execute this logic inside the component you're trying to navigate to.